# How to fix the loop to get the values I'm passig as an argument?

Tags: java, file, iteration

I'm trying to parse the images and photos filenames, so I develop a method to explore the given path and get all the images and photos, after that according to a certain criteria it get information from the file names.

Now, for some reason the loop is not getting the individual files from the array, I've been debugging the code and I get this information from the debug console:

```
folder = {File@520}"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources"
   0 = {File@533}"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources\images"
      0 = {File@540}"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources\images\img0001"
         0 = {File@540}"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources\images\img0001\IMG-0001-23.JPG"
...
```

So is getting the images from folder, bur for some reason is not getting them after that.

```
public ProcessedImages process(File folder ,String group,String tag) throws Exception{  //folder: "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources" group: "exterior" tag: "Photo"
   ImageHierarchy imageInfo = null;
   ProcessedImages collection = new ProcessedImages(); // collection: ProcessedImage@523
   File[] imageFiles = getFiles(folder, group, tag); //imageFiles: File[0]@524 folder: "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Resources" 
   for (File imageFile : imageFiles) { //ImageFiles: File[0]@524
      imageInfo = extractType1Info(imageFile, tag, group);
      if(imageInfo!=null){
         collection.AddImage(imageInfo);
      }
      else{
         imageInfo = extractType2Info(imageFile,tag, group); //tag: "Photo" group: "exterior"
         if(imageInfo!=null){
            collection.AddImage(imageInfo); imageInfo: null
         }
      }
   }
   return collection;
}
```

getFiles method:

```java
private File[] getFiles(File folder ,String group,String tag){

        ArrayList<File> fileList= new ArrayList<File>();

        if(folder!=null)
        {
            ArrayList<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>();
            directories.add(folder);

            while(!directories.isEmpty() && (folder = directories.remove(0))!=null)
            {
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                if(listOfFiles!=null)
                {
                    for ( File file : listOfFiles) {
                        if(file.isFile()){

                            if((group!=null && file.getName().contains(group)) || (tag!=null && file.getName().contains(tag))){
                                System.out.println(file.getName());
                                fileList.add(file);
                            }

                        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
                            directories.add(file);                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList.toArray(new File[]{});

    }
```

I should get all the images and save them in the array imageFiles and then interate it using the loop and the imageFile variable to save it in the collection.

Comment: Does ```getFiles``` return an array of all the files recursively or only the first level in the input folder? I suspect that is the latter and so the problem. If that is the case you need to change getFiles to do the recursion or you do it outside in the calling code.

Comment: This is the return of getFiles: ``` return fileList.toArray(new File[]{});```

Comment: can u post  complete getFiles() method

Comment: Done @RamanShrivastava

Comment: Looking at the code and the values arguments are taking (the debugger ones) it seems that only files whose name contains "exterior" or "Photo" would be output. Can you verify that you have such files? In the input example you only list one image file whose name does not match neither of those ("IMG-0001-23.JPG").